# Displaying powers (to the power of 2, 3, 4 etc)?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to display 2, 3 etc raised as you would when working with maths equations?

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
 Html.fromHtml("2"+"<sup>-2</sup>");
 //shows 2 raised to -2
```

similarly use

```
    <sub> x</sub>
```

tag for subscript

Answer (score 2):

KISS. Use [unicode superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUnicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)... unless your font do not contains them of course.